# Does Laravel latest version keep session row in database like Codeigniter lates version?

Tags: codeigniter, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently working on Codeigniter latest version and I try to create user system management and I've set session as below code But Codeigniter doesn't delete existing row of old session row and they try to insert new one instead.
It might make my table user stuck or because it will store more (more than 5000rows) row of user session or my database connection might going to get errors if all session row keep forever and don't delete or update existing rows of session data.

**How Laravel will keep their session row in their database forever or they will automaticaly delete row of their user after their user close their browser or sing out**.

moreover, I don't see my IP show up on my database.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

[image]

Please help to solve my problem and if possible let me some idear

Comment: I don't know what laravel does but isn't the expiration date the problem here?

Comment: what mean want me to corrent sess_expiration right? I want my user can login and keep their session longer than 2 hour although I changes sess_expiration=100 it still the same thing it still keep all the row of table session in db don't delete

Comment: Perhaps you've to delete the expired sessions you're own. You can create a cron for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Laravel, you can [store session data](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session#session-drivers) a file, a database, a cookie, or a cache like memcached or redis. Laravel cleans up expired session entries based on a `lottery` setting in `app/config/session.php` in v4.2, and in `config/session.php` in v5.0:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/
'lottery' => [2, 100],
```

Adjusting the `lottery` values changes the odds that garbage collection will occur on any given request. To force a purge, setting the odds to 1:1 (i.e. if the two values in `lottery` match) will force Laravel to delete all expired session data on the next request.