# Laravel delete DB session record after logout event

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4

im building an application with laravel 4.2

Id like to know how laravel remove sessions records on DB after Auth::logout() call...

Its still there in my table.. with an empty payload but still there

thanks for reply

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727139/does-laravel-latest-version-keep-session-row-in-database-like-codeigniter-lates it'll get cleared eventually, you can set `'lottery' => [1, 1],` in `app/config/session.php` to delete all expired on a given request, as mentioned in the answer

Comment: yes ive seen this lottery field .. but it seems doesnt work on log out...

Comment: Have you fired off another interaction with the session after logging out with the lottery set like: `'lottery' => [1, 1],` ?

Comment: it looks like everything isnt changed .. my  session db record is still there with an empty payload

Comment: and this is the larave DatabaseSessionHandler /**
  * {@inheritDoc}
  */
 public function destroy($sessionId)
 {
  $this->getQuery()->where('id' , $sessionId)->delete();
 }

 /**
  * {@inheritDoc}
  */
 public function gc($lifetime)
 {
  $this->getQuery()->where('last_activity', '<=', time() - $lifetime)->delete();

 }

Comment: Was that a yes or a no?

Comment: I mean did you try what I said - Have you fired off another interaction with the session after logging out with the lottery set like: `'lottery' => [1, 1],` ?

Comment: yes i try but i cant... my session is empty ... so i cant do nothing but the record is still there.. id like to know how to handle it

Comment: Well I guess when you hit the route to logout you can pass the session ID to an implementation of DatabaseSessionHandler and call the destroy method on it, then do `Auth::logout()`. Would that work?

Comment: ive done this yet... but i miss something .. if i do that the record will be deleted on logout event but when i call the login page again the application regenerate that record.. i miss something .... could it be the auth::attempt() method on login?

Comment: If you have implemented that, please update your question with the code maybe someone else will see with with a better idea about this issue.